# How to repeat sequence when condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

I have found variations of this question, and I know modulos can possibly be used but I am having a difficult time putting it all together.

I have a sequence of observations by ID and seconds. When the cumulitive amount of seconds by id increments greater than 5 seconds, I would like to restart the count. Could someone help me answer this question in dplyr?

Original df

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 val = c(2,10,12,15,17,2,4,7,8,12,15,20,25))

df
   id val
1   1   2
2   1  10
3   1  12
4   1  15
5   1  17
6   2   2
7   2   4
8   2   7
9   2   8
10  3  12
11  3  15
12  3  20
13  3  25
```

Desired Outcome

```
finalResult
   id val reset
1   1   2     1
2   1  10     2
3   1  12     2
4   1  15     3
5   1  17     3
6   2   2     1
7   2   4     1
8   2   7     2
9   2   8     2
10  3  12     1
11  3  15     1
12  3  20     2
13  3  25     3
```

**Edit**

Thanks for the responses yesterday but I encountered some problems with the given solutions.

On this data set the code works on some instances.

```
sub.df <- structure(list(`ID` = c("1", 
                                                "1", "1", 
                                                "1", "1", 
                                                "1", "1", 
                                                "1", "1"
), dateFormat = structure(c(1479955726, 1479955726, 1483703713, 
                            1495190809, 1495190809, 1497265079, 1497265079, 1474023059, 1474023061
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")), .Names = c("ID", 
                                                                           "dateFormat"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                            "data.frame"))
```

Solution Used:

```
jj <- sub.df %>% 
  group_by(`ID`) %>% 
  arrange(`ID`,`dateFormat`)%>%
  mutate(totalTimeInt = difftime(dateFormat,first(dateFormat),units = 'secs'))%>%
  mutate(totalTimeFormat   = as.numeric(totalTimeInt))%>%
  mutate(reset = cumsum(
    Reduce(
      function(x, y) 
        if (x + y >= 5) 0 
        else x + y, 

        diff(totalTimeFormat), init = 0, accumulate = TRUE
    ) == 0
  ))%>%
  mutate(reset_2 = cumsum(
    accumulate(
      diff(totalTimeFormat), 
      ~if (.x + .y >= 5) 0 else .x + .y, 
      .init = 0
    ) == 0
  ))
```

Outcome

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID          dateFormat  totalTimeInt totalTimeFormat reset reset_2
  <chr>              <dttm>        <time>           <dbl> <int>   <int>
1     1 2016-09-16 05:50:59        0 secs               0     1       1
2     1 2016-09-16 05:51:01        2 secs               2     1       1
3     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46  5932667 secs         5932667     2       2
4     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46  5932667 secs         5932667     3       3
5     1 2017-01-06 05:55:13  9680654 secs         9680654     4       4
6     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49 21167750 secs        21167750     5       5
7     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49 21167750 secs        21167750     6       6
8     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59 23242020 secs        23242020     7       7
9     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59 23242020 secs        23242020     8       8
```

What happens is that for the first two observation it correctly counts that as 1 instance. When it reaches the third and fourth observation this should only be counted as two observations as there was essentially no time that passed between those two instances.

Correct Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID          dateFormat  totalTimeInt totalTimeFormat reset reset_2
  <chr>              <dttm>        <time>           <dbl> <int>   <int>
1     1 2016-09-16 05:50:59        0 secs               0     1       1
2     1 2016-09-16 05:51:01        2 secs               2     1       1
3     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46  5932667 secs         5932667     2       2
4     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46  5932667 secs         5932667     2       2
5     1 2017-01-06 05:55:13  9680654 secs         9680654     3       3
6     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49 21167750 secs        21167750     4       4
7     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49 21167750 secs        21167750     4       4
8     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59 23242020 secs        23242020     5       5
9     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59 23242020 secs        23242020     5       5
```

Comment: It should be noted that in the id group # 1, when val goes from 12 to 15, the reset changes, but in group # 3 it doesn't.  My answer below, is consistent with the logic in the first group.

Comment: @JosephWood That's because in group # 1 at that point the reference for resetting is `10` while for group # 3 it's `12`

Comment: @duckmayr, thanks for clarifying this point (i.e. the reference point is not simply the first value in the group, but the value at which the difference of the previous reference is greater than or equal to 5). My now deleted answer was naive and incorrectly only referred to the first value in that group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` (or `purrr::accumulate`, if you prefer), you can reset the running difference when it is greater than or equal to 5. Calling `cumsum` on whether that total is 0 will return the number of resets.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 val = c(2,10,12,15,17,2,4,7,8,12,15,20,25))

df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(reset = cumsum(
        Reduce(
            function(x, y) if (x + y >= 5) 0 else x + y, 
            diff(val), init = 0, accumulate = TRUE
        ) == 0
    ))
#> # A tibble: 13 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>       id   val reset
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1     2     1
#>  2     1    10     2
#>  3     1    12     2
#>  4     1    15     3
#>  5     1    17     3
#>  6     2     2     1
#>  7     2     4     1
#>  8     2     7     2
#>  9     2     8     2
#> 10     3    12     1
#> 11     3    15     1
#> 12     3    20     2
#> 13     3    25     3
```

or with `purrr::accumulate`,

```r
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(reset = cumsum(
        accumulate(
            diff(val), 
            ~if (.x + .y >= 5) 0 else .x + .y, 
            .init = 0
        ) == 0
    ))
#> # A tibble: 13 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>       id   val reset
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1     2     1
#>  2     1    10     2
#>  3     1    12     2
#>  4     1    15     3
#>  5     1    17     3
#>  6     2     2     1
#>  7     2     4     1
#>  8     2     7     2
#>  9     2     8     2
#> 10     3    12     1
#> 11     3    15     1
#> 12     3    20     2
#> 13     3    25     3
```

---

Regarding the edit, the issue is that some of the diffs are 0, which is the same as what it's counting to see resets. The simplest solution is to use `NA` instead of zero as a reset value:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sub.df <- structure(list(`ID` = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
                         dateFormat = structure(c(1479955726, 1479955726, 1483703713, 
                            1495190809, 1495190809, 1497265079, 1497265079, 1474023059, 1474023061), 
                            class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")), 
                    .Names = c("ID", "dateFormat"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

sub.df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(ID, dateFormat) %>%
    mutate(reset = cumsum(is.na(
               accumulate(diff(dateFormat), 
                          ~{
                              s <- sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE);
                              if (s >= 5) NA else s
                          }, 
                          .init = NA)
    )))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID          dateFormat reset
#>   <chr>              <dttm> <int>
#> 1     1 2016-09-16 05:50:59     1
#> 2     1 2016-09-16 05:51:01     1
#> 3     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46     2
#> 4     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46     2
#> 5     1 2017-01-06 05:55:13     3
#> 6     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49     4
#> 7     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49     4
#> 8     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59     5
#> 9     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59     5
```

Ultimately this approach faces limitations, too, though, as if any values actually *are* `NA`, it will increment similarly. A more robust solution would be to return a list of two elements from each iteration, one for the total with resets, and one for the reset count. This is more work to implement, though:

```r
sub.df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(ID, dateFormat) %>%
    mutate(total_reset = accumulate(
        transpose(list(total = diff(dateFormat), reset = rep(0, n() - 1))),
        ~{
            s <- .x$total + .y$total;
            if (s >= 5) {
                data_frame(total = 0, reset = .x$reset + 1)
            } else {
                data_frame(total = s, reset = .x$reset)
            }
        }, 
        .init = data_frame(total = 0, reset = 1)
    )) %>% 
    unnest()
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID          dateFormat total reset
#>   <chr>              <dttm> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 2016-09-16 05:50:59     0     1
#> 2     1 2016-09-16 05:51:01     2     1
#> 3     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46     0     2
#> 4     1 2016-11-23 20:48:46     0     2
#> 5     1 2017-01-06 05:55:13     0     3
#> 6     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49     0     4
#> 7     1 2017-05-19 05:46:49     0     4
#> 8     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59     0     5
#> 9     1 2017-06-12 05:57:59     0     5
```

The total looks a little silly, but if you look at the diff, it's actually correct.

Comment: thanks for that answer. It works brilliantly. But could you please explain the `Reduce` function? I'm not understanding that part.

Comment: `Reduce` applies a binary (2-variable) function to successive terms of a vector. By default, it collapses everything down to a single term, so `Reduce(\`+\`, 1:4)` is the same as `sum(1:4)`, though it calculates as `(((1 + 2) + 3) + 4)`. However, if you add `accumulate = TRUE`, it saves the intermediary terms, so `Reduce(\`+\`, 1:4, accumulate = TRUE)` is equivalent to `cumsum(1:4)`. It handles lists (including data frames) well, e.g. `Reduce(\`+\`, mtcars)`, and will accept a binary function of any complexity. If `init` is supplied, it is used as the first value of the vector.

Comment: I ran into an issue with the solution. I would appreciate any input if you know how to correct it. Thank you.

Comment: See the edit. It's because it's counting zeros in the diff, but some of the diffs for that data _are_ zero.

Comment: @alistaire, thanks for the thorough solution. I’ve learned quite a bit over the past two days digesting your very well put together answer.

Comment: agreed. At @alistaire, I'm just curious at where you learned techniques like this? What type of material do you review and what type of work requires code like this? If you don't mind sharing.

Comment: Writing and reading answers here, plus the docs. `Reduce` follows the idiom of `lapply`/`Map`, so once you get one down, it's not that hard to extrapolate. [R4DS](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#reduce-and-accumulate) has some explanations and exercises which may be helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong (EDIT: I was proven wrong, by [alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire)'s [brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681808/8386140), though I'm leaving this approach here for now), but I think this is one of the instances where you actually need a loop because the value of `reset` in each row is going to depend on what happened for previous rows. I'm hopeful [Joseph Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4408538/joseph-wood) will come up with something smarter than this, but in the meantime here is a naive approach, which utilizes `dplyr` as requested. We can make the following function

```
count_resets <- function(x) {
    N <- length(x)
    value <- 1
    result <- rep(1, N)
    threshold <- x[1]
    for ( i in 2:N ) {
        if ( abs(x[i] - threshold) >= 5) {
            value <- value + 1
            threshold <- x[i]
        }
        result[i] <- value
    }
    return(result)
}
```

And apply it by `id` using `dplyr`'s `group_by()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(reset = count_resets(val))

# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
      id   val reset
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     2     1
 2     1    10     2
 3     1    12     2
 4     1    15     3
 5     1    17     3
 6     2     2     1
 7     2     4     1
 8     2     7     2
 9     2     8     2
10     3    12     1
11     3    15     1
12     3    20     2
13     3    25     3
```